# Substituting strings in many data frame rows without using a loop

Tags: r

I am doing a substitution on a column of character strings in a large dataframe (several 100k rows), and I have to do it several times over the course of a lengthy routine. I would like to write this in a vectorized way, but can't figure out a method to do it. At the moment I have to use a full-length loop, taking several minutes each time, to step through each row separately.

The reason why I can't do it functionally seems to be that for each row value I need to be able to reference it specifically in a `str_extract` (or `grepl`) command, which I don't know how to do w/o an index. (The objective is to use 0's to pad the leading numerical part of each variable-length string out to 6 digits. An entry might look like "1234XYZ".)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

df$A[i] <- gsub("^[[:digit:]]+",
paste(paste(rep(0,6-nchar(str_extract(df$A[i],"^[[:digit:]]+"))), collapse=""), 
str_extract(df$A[i], "^[[:digit:]]+"), collapse=""), df$A[i])

}
```

Obviously the following, which I naively attempted as the "vectorized version", doesn't work because `str_extract` returns a vector with an entry for each row of df:

```
df$A <- gsub("^[[:digit:]]+", 
paste(paste(rep(0,6-nchar(str_extract(df$A,"^[[:digit:]]+"))), collapse=""), 
str_extract(df$A, "^[[:digit:]]+"), collapse=""), df$A)
```

Can this be done without a loop?

Comment: Can you include a little of your data.frame `df`?  `dput(head(df))`. Otherwise your code isn't reproducible and we can't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without reproducible data, but I think this will work for you

```
front <- str_pad(str_extract(df$A, "^[[:digit:]]+"), 6, pad="0")
back  <- str_extract(df$A, "[^0-9]+")
df$A <- paste(front, back, sep="")
```

Comment: Nifty! That does it. Two revelations: hadn't thought of splitting off all back ends & all front ends in separate blocks; and overlooked `str_pad`. Thanks! (Actual implementation is a little less compact, as I find I need to weed out NAs between the split and pad steps.)

Comment: I just realized the clincher here is that `stringr` methods are all vectorized, whereas `grep` \ `sub` aren't. I.e. using `str_replace` instead of `gsub` in my original vectorized sample works fine. Heh :)